# Datatable in shiny app in multiple browsers reset the first session values

Tags: shiny, datatables, shiny-server, shinyapps

Im trying to use a datatable to input data on a shiny app, it works perfectly until i open a second or more browser (sessions) once i do that the only datatable that works (saving data) is the last one open. And the others just do not work until the browser is reset and then that table takes control. I cant work on multiple sessions with this error.

The code for my table is this:

```
output[[unique_id]] <- renderDataTable(server = TRUE, future = FALSE,{
      datatable(
        session$userData[[paste0("catching_tables_", session_id)]]$play_table_catching(),
          rownames = FALSE,
          selection = "none",
          escape = FALSE,
          class = DT:::DT2BSClass(c('compact', 'cell-border')),
          # callback = htmlwidgets::JS(
          #   "$('table.dataTable.no-footer').css('border-bottom', 'none');"
          # ),
          options = list(
            pageLength = 50,
            columnDefs = list(
              list(width = '300px', targets = "_all"),
              list(className = 'dt-center', targets = 0:11),
              list(visible = FALSE, targets = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4))
            ),
            dom = 'r',
            ordering = FALSE,
            rowCallback = htmlwidgets::JS("function(r,d) {$(r).attr('height', '10px')}"),
            preDrawCallback=JS(
              'function() {
                         Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node());}'),
            drawCallback= JS(
              'function(settings) {
                         Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node());}'),
            initComplete = htmlwidgets::JS(
              "function(settings, json) {",
              "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#002D72', 'color': 'white', 'font-family': 'Helvetica'});",
              "}"
            )
          )
        )
      })
```

Can please point me in the right direction? all my tables, and variables are set so they are unique to the session.

I just tried to make every part of my code to be fully session independent but still cant manage to overcome the issue of the last table rendered being the one in control, instead of every table to keep active within each session